# Cannot manage to increase font-size with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am quite new at this, and after many courses I am now starting to create a website, using Bootstrap.
I have an issue with increasing the font size of mfizz icons. If I list said icons in a  as

elements with an  tag, I am able to change their font size, however unable to create padding.

As I am making use of Bootstrap columns, I could do without the list to achieve what I want, however I seem to be unable to select the icons in any way, whether with an id, class, child selector etc. It does work if I insert style= in HTML, however I'd like to understand why it doesn't via CSS.

Would you know how to overcome this?

```css
#selected-icon {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" align="center">
    <div class="div-tech-skills">
      <i id="selected-icon" class="icon-csharp"></i>
      <i class="icon-bootstrap"></i>
      <i class="icon-css3"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide working example. as your icon are not visible

Comment: Your question isn't very clear Alfonso. @MaxiGui Check out this [Pen](https://codepen.io/ni_l/pen/abZdazz) for the icons.

Comment: Many thanks all, but I resolved the problem somehow. All it needed was less encapsulation.